# How to use alternative name for certain directory in windows?

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-sdk-2.1

I want to know how can I use another name for user name in windows. I have white space in my user name and I already have many software installed with that directory. Now i am setting up Android sdk and it says there could be problem because of white space. I remember something like a different name for a folder to reach there.

Comment: https://winaero.com/blog/rename-user-profile-folder-windows-10/

Comment: If you rename the folder and update the "ProfileImagePath" in the registry, there will probably still be a lot of references in the profile that hard code the old location. You could try adding a bind mount (junction) from the old name to the new name (e.g. `mklink /j "C:\Users\user name" "C:\Users\user_name"`), which should allow programs that hard code the old name to continue working with the old name.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for what is commonly known as *"short name"*. You can pass the `/x` option to the [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) command to get the short name for any given directory.

Comment: Way easier than what was mentioned in the comments